# Help needed in deriving the complex root of raised cosine power spectrum

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fourier-analysis

The raised cosine power spectrum (energy spectrum) is defined as

$$|\hat{\phi}|^2 =
\begin{cases}
1,& \text {if} |\omega| \leq \pi (1-b)\\
\dfrac{1}{2}[1+\cos\dfrac{|\omega|-\pi(1-b)}{2b}],& \text{if} \pi(1-b)\leq|\omega|\leq\pi(1+b)\\
0,& \text{if } |\omega|\geq \pi (1-b).
\end{cases}$$

The square roots  i.e $\phi(\omega)$ are given as
$$\hat{\phi_1}(\omega) =
\begin{cases}
1,& \text {if} |\omega| \leq \pi (1-b)\\
\cos\dfrac{|\omega|\pi(1-b)}{4b},&  \text{if }\pi(1-b)\leq|\omega|\leq\pi(1+b)\\ 0,&    \text{if } |\omega|\geq \pi (1-b)
\end{cases}$$

and

$$\hat{\phi_2}(\omega) =
\begin{cases}
1,&   \text{if }  \omega\leq \pi (1-b)\\
\dfrac{1}{2}[1+e^{(1/2b)(\omega-\pi(1-b)}],&   \text{if }\pi(1-b)\leq\omega\leq\pi(1+b) \\
0,&   \text{if } \omega\geq \pi (1-b),
\end{cases}$$

where $\hat{\phi_1}(\omega)$ and $\hat{\phi_2}(\omega)$ are the fourier transforms of $\hat{\phi_1}(\omega)$ and $ \hat{\phi_2}(\omega).\\ $

Can someone help me out in deriving  $\hat{\phi_2}(\omega)$ and in finding the inverse fourier transforms i.e $\phi_{1}(x)$ and $\phi_{2}(x)$?

Where $\phi_{1}(x)= \dfrac{\sin\pi(1-b)x+4bx \cos\pi(1+b)x}{\pi x(1-(4bx)^2)}\\$

$\phi_{2}(x)= \dfrac{\sin\pi(1-b)x+ \sin\pi(1+b)x}{2\pi x(1+2bx)} = \dfrac{\cos(\pi bx)}{(1+2bx)} sinc(\pi x)\\$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do tell us what you have tried yourself.

Comment: After getting the real root I tried to expand it in terms of the power of  e that is $cos(\theta)= (e^i(\theta)+e^((-i)(\theta))/2$ but I could not get this form. Again after getting the real root I tried to multiply it with complex root of unity even then I could not get the desired form. Moreover the inverse fourier transforms are too difficult for me to find in this form.